# What is "=>" meaning in the react-motion code?

Tags: reactjs

The react-motion library is really amazing, the '=>' operator confused me though. During my implementation, it always show me some syntax error such as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {". I checked my code and I was unable to find the bug. I can't understand what is the meaning of "=>" and what syntax should follow. Could anyone solve my doubt? here's my code:

```
<Motion defaultStyle={this.getDefaults()} style={this.getEnds()}>
            {current => {

                    Object.keys(current).map(key => {
                        let {rotate,scale} = current[key].val;
                        let style = {
                            transform: `rotate(${rotate}deg) scale(${scale})`
                        };
                        return 
                            <div
                                key={key}
                                className="block"
                                style={style}>
                                {key}
                            </div>


                    })}

            }
        </Motion>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like an [Ecmascript 6 arrow function](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html).

Answer (score 3):

The `=>` is the ES6 way, known as an arrow function expression or a fat arrow function, of declaring an anonymous function with its `this` set lexically to the object at hand.

In order for you to use this language construct you need to transpile your code through a tool like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) or only support Chrome 45+, Firefox 22+ or Microsoft Edge.